# Does Ubuntu 17 use the "pure" Gnome or Ubuntu Gnome?

Tags: gnome

Does Ubuntu 17 Desktop use the "pure" Gnome or Ubuntu Gnome version?

Comment: You mean Ubuntu 17.10, right?

Answer (score 4):

The Ubuntu Desktop in Ubuntu 17.10 uses GNOME instead of Unity, but they've made a few changes in the GNOME desktop to make it similar to Unity. Ubuntu GNOME Desktop in Ubuntu 17.10 has the combination of purple desktop, applications launcher dock and dashboard that users of Unity in previous Ubuntu releases are familiar with.